# How to display specific number of notifications in android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I am implementing push notifications in android, what I need to do is to show specific number of notification is notification bar. Let's say I have to show recent 5 notifications. I received 5 notification and show them up. Upon receiving 6th notification, I must have to discard oldest notification and so on. 
Further I don't want to collapse notifications but show each as a separate notification.

**Edit:**

There is a function available in NotificationManager.

```
void cancel(int id)
Cancel a previously shown notification.
```

And to check how many notifications are still visible in notification bar of your app. A nNotificationListenerService's method can be used named `getActiveNotifications()`. However a problem still exist that `getActiveNotifications()` exist in android API 18 and more. Any solution for API level <18 ?

Comment: If you are voting it as -1 you should leave a comment such that I could improve my question if it is not looks valid to you.

Comment: You should read the SO's faq, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have read complete article on android developers about GSM and Notifications. Then implemented it end to end. Problem is just to remove oldest notification if I am receiving more notifications then a specific number.

Comment: If you read it then you know that there is the id parameter in cancel and notify methods of NotificationManager, so where is the problem?

Comment: I read its developer's guide article, not its References. My mistake, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can cancel a notification easily, by supplying the id of the notification: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)

**however**, you can also update a notification by reusing the id, you don't have to cancel it.

My plan of attack would be to iterate through 5 predefined ids to create the notifications with, then reuse the "oldest" id on the sixth notification.   This would replace the oldest notification with the new one.

Comment: Thanks, good idea.. the trick is, how would I know how many notification are cancelled by the user and how many are still remaining in notification bar?

Comment: well, since getActiveNotifications is only available 18+ (or 19?) I think you might have to use the delete intent to keep track of them - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29